# React - Strange Flicker on Animation only for the first click

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, transition

I'm making an off canvas menu and when you click on the hamburger to open the menu you get a flicker. If you then close the off canvas menu and re-open it. The flicker is no more. This is also the same for the dropdowns that I have inside the offcanvas menu.

This is my CSS for the offCanvas transition:

```
const OffcanvasContainer = styled(Container)`
  width: 280px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: ${props => props.theme.offCanvasBackground};
  box-shadow: 3px 0px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);

  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -400px;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: left .25s;

  ${props => (props.open ? 'left: 0;' : null)}
`;
```

I should point out that the open prop is actually a state that gets triggered on click, code below:

```
openOffcanvas() {
  this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
}

<Offcanvas
  open={this.state.open}
/>
```

So I've also tried adding this line of css to the body tag as I read it might fix the problem but it hasn't.

```
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
```

I'm curious if anyone else has ran into this problem and how to fix it.

**** Update ****
If I add a delay to the transition this fixes the problem. So maybe I need to wait for the data of the component to load before the transition takes place.

Now looking for suggestions on the above.